# Dynamically creating new URL in Django

Tags: python, django, url

i want to know how to create new pages in Django after a logged-in User clicks "create new group" links.

```
class Blob(models.Model):    #models.py

    Owner = models.OneToOneField(User)
    From = models.CharField()
    To = models.CharField()
    Leaving_Date = models.DateField()
    Leaving_Time = models.TimeField()
    Lower_Time = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
    Upper_Time = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
    URL = models.URLField()
```

Each entry has a Owner. User queries in this table and if no matching entry is found, he is prompted to create a new entry in this table.

How would you fill this URL field and corresponding changes in views.py and url.py. Asking users for it doesn't look good.

Edit: I am thinking of creating a random string of fixed length, like 'xcedfr' and then appending it to the base URL, it would be good if every entry have unique URL

Comment: what is yor question? are you asking what should you choose to fill the url or you want help on writing python code?

Comment: How and what should i choose to fill in URL field. Python code would clear answer but i do not expect it.

Comment: If you don't want to use the plain id number, you can convert it to a short string of pseudorandom characters using hashids. http://hashids.org/python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a matter of personal opinion about how you prefer your links should be:

1. you can use `uuid4` for url, (PRO: url is unique and hard to guess)
2. using pk (primary key) is also another option (CON: user can guess next items by simply adding the counter)
3. exact datetime of creating this object (if your service is under heavy load it might not work sometimes)
4. pk-title (your model doesn't have title but generally it's good too, fixes issue of #2)
5. ...

these are all some suggestions I think they will help you get an idea of how to fill that field :-)

(note: make sure that field is always unique, maybe adding unique=True is a good idea)

Comment: Currently i am using id of the entry to create new URL.